# KVM switch doesn't work with only 1 computer

Tags: windows-10, kvm-switch

I have been using a KVM switch for my keyboard and mouse only (it's a USB KVM) for about 2 weeks. It's inputs are my desktop PC and my work laptop. At first everything was fine, now when I unplug the laptop at the end of the day (and only the desktop remains connected), my mouse and keyboard (and the indicator light on the KVM) flash like crazy and the mouse/keyboard no longer work. This happens only if it's the laptop I unplug. If I instead unplug the desktop USB connection (and leave the laptop connected), the keyboard and mouse work on the laptop without any issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more specific information by editing your question?

Comment: Sure, what information?

Answer (score 0):

USB KVM needs power, ensure your USB on your workstation has the lightning bolt or use a USB 3.0+ port on your workstation.

[image]